# Непроверяемые безударные гласные

Tags: орфография, фонетика

Какие слова относятся к непроверяемым безударным гласным?

Comment: слова к гласным не относятся )))

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке множество слов, заинствованный из других языков. В них-то и бывают непроверяемые безударные гласные. Такие слова нужно просто запомнить или сверять из правописание с орфографическим словарем.
Примеры: *бечевка, жюри, корреспондент*.
Также следует помнить, что эти слова могут быть парными - с них, в зависимости от смысла, может меняться безударная гласная.
Примеры: *компания - кампания, сеньор - синьор*.